# Parallel package using mclapply works with only 2 cores instead of all 4

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I have this example data

```
library("parallel")
DV<-runif(1000,min=-5,max=5)
RV_1<-runif(1000,min=-5,max=5)
RV_2<--runif(1000,min=-5,max=5)
df<-data.frame(DV,RV_1,RV_2)
fun<-function(x){
  n<-neuralnet(DV~RV_1+RV_2,data=df,hidden=x)
  return(n)
}
```

and if I use for example

```
mclapply(c(1:5),fun)
```

the task manager shows that only 2 cores works on 100 %.
But if I check this

```
detectCores()
```

It sees all 4 cores.
Any advices how to fix it?
I've bought new i5-4960k for improve my computation speed but it won't be much better this way. Thanks anybody

Comment: SOLVED by using mclapply(c(1:5),fun,mc.cores=4)

Comment: Seeing you solved it, you can put your answer below and accept it so others who come across the question know you have an answer.

Comment: Thank you, it shows that I can accept answer in 2 days.

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED by using mclapply(c(1:5),fun,mc.cores=4)